# Writing into excel file with OLEDB

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Does anyone know how to write to an excel file (.xls) via OLEDB in C#?  I'm doing the following:

```
   OleDbCommand dbCmd = new OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE [test$] (...)", connection);
   dbCmd.CommandTimeout = mTimeout;
   results = dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But I get an OleDbException thrown with message:

> "Cannot modify the design of table
>   'test$'.  It is in a read-only
>   database."

My connection seems fine and I can select data fine but I can't seem to insert data into the excel file, does anyone know how I get read/write access to the excel file via OLEDB?

Comment: Does the workbook already have a sheet named test$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `ReadOnly=False;` to your connection string

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=fifa_ng_db.xls;Mode=ReadWrite;ReadOnly=false;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";
```

Comment: Not quite correct - using the ReadOnly attribute causes the error "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException : Could not find installable ISAM." It is the IMEX=0 that prevents the file being readonly. The string that worked for me (C#) is: @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;MaxScanRows=0;IMEX=0"";";

Comment: All that is essential is `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Docs\Test.xls;Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes""` MaxScanRows and IMEX depend on registry settings to some extent and are often not required.

Answer (score 14):

I was also looking for and answer but Zorantula's solution didn't work for me.
I found the solution on http://www.cnblogs.com/zwwon/archive/2009/01/09/1372262.html

I removed the `ReadOnly=false` parameter and the `IMEX=1` extended property.

The `IMEX=1` property opens the workbook in import mode, so structure-modifying commands (like `CREATE TABLE` or `DROP TABLE`) don't work.

My working connection string is:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=workbook.xls;Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";"
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem. Only remove the extended property `IMEX=1`. That will solve your problem. Your table will be created in your Excel file...

Answer (score 1):

A couple questions:

- Does the user that executes your app (you?) have permission to write to the file?
- Is the file read-only?
- What is your connection string?

If you're using ASP, you'll need to add the IUSER_* user as in [this example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195951/).

Answer (score 0):

- How do I check the permissions for writing to an excel file for my application (I'm using excel 2007)?
- The file is not read only, or protected (to my knowledge).
- My connection String is:

> "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data
>   Source=fifa_ng_db.xls;Mode=ReadWrite;Extended
>   Properties=\"Excel
>   8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\""

Comment: Check the permissions by right-clicking on it and hitting the security or permissions tab.  Is the Excel file closed when you connect to it?

Comment: You should try IMEX=0 instead

Answer (score 0):

Further to Michael Haren's answer. The account you will need to grant Modify permissions to the XLS file will likely be NETWORK SERVICE if this code is running in an ASP.NET application (it's specified in the IIS Application Pool). To find out exactly what account your code is running as, you can do a simple:

```
Response.Write(Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running under ASP.NET, and encountered both "Cannot modify the design..." and "Cannot locate ISAM..." error messages.

I found that I needed to:

**a**) Use the following connection string:

`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;';Data Source=" + {path to file};`

Note I too had issues with `IMEX=1` and with the `ReadOnly=false` attributes in the connection string.

**b**) Grant EVERYONE full permissions to the folder in which the file was being written.  Normally, ASP.NET runs under the NETWORK SERVICE account, and that already had permissions. However, the OleDb code is unmanaged, so it must run under some other security context.  (I am currently too lazy to figure out which account, so I just used EVERYONE.)