# How to create and update spreadsheet using OLEDB in C#?

Tags: excel, file

HI! all 
I am creating .xls spreadsheet file using following code

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\temp.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'"))
{
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE [NewSheet] ([Column1] string, [Column2] string)", conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

but i am getting an exception at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Exception is: *Cannot modify the design of table 'NewSheet'.  It is in a read-only database.*

Please help me to resolve this

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You need to add readonly= false to your connection string, see:

[Writing into excel file with OLEDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57987/writing-into-excel-file-with-oledb)

Comment: Thank you so much.
I am getting following Exception at:  conn.open();
Exception is:      "Could not find installable ISAM."


Please help

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) will let you open, modify and save Excel workbooks, has no limits on the structure of a workbook, and does not rely on OLEDB or anything else (other than .NET 2.0+).

You can see live samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it yourself.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC