# When I try read Excel with OLE DB all values are empty

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have done a little program to parser excel. It works fine only when before to execute it I open Excel file manually (is not it strange?). I.e. first I open excel file, second I execute program and I get good results

[image]

If I don't open excel before to execute it I get empty values

[image]

My connection string (excel file has extension .XLSX):

```
connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                   "Data Source=" + path + "\\" + f.Name + ";" +
                   "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
```

My code to open connection with oleDB:

```
using (OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    cnn.Open();
    ...
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetNames[i] + "]";
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt); // Now 'dt' should has all data
}
```

Also, I have installed *AccessDatabaseEngine.exe* and *AccessRuntime.exe*

Obviously, my purpose is run the program without having to manually open the file. Any suggestion?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Same problem as this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700863/c-sharp-read-open-excel-file-through-oledb

Comment: I have not found a solution there.

Comment: What *else* are you doing? What kind of file are you trying to open? Is it a *real* excel file or a CSV/HTML file with an Excel extension? What does it contain? If your code works the second time, it's because Excel modified the original file.

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos Is it real excel that contains 14 colums with interger and string values. The order does not matter, the program works fine  when previously I open manually excel file (First image).

Comment: @robBerto: just pointing out there is no easy solution with oleDB which wants exclusive use of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it a real pain when I tried to get OleDb and Excel to play nicely together.  Fortunately, I found a much better approach: [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

> EPPlus is a .net library that reads and writes Excel 2007/2010 files using the Open Office Xml format (xlsx).

Open source, feature rich and easy to use.  If at all possible, use it instead of OleDb.

Comment: The suggestion is appreciated, but I'm so close to solving not want to leave this approach.

Comment: Finally I have followed your suggestion and I am very satisfied. In half an hour my solution was ready.

Comment: I don't normally like to suggest a different solution, but in this case I went though much pain with OleDb and Excel and know that EPPlus is a much better path.  Glad it worked for you,