# read/write a simple excel file using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to find a simple way of writing an excel file in c#, but everything that I've found on  thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options available to you

The First is to use Interop Assemblies here is a link to some sample code on how to do that [Write Data to Excel using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19509/Write-Data-to-Excel-using-C)

The Second option is to use OLEDB.  There is some information on Stack Overflow on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57987/writing-into-excel-file-with-oledb)

Answer (score 1):

Use epplus as mentioned above,It makes it really simple. This is the code for a spread sheet i created with it today.

```
            using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            //Give the worksheet a name
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Inventory as of " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
            //dt is a datable that i am turning into an excel document
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
            //Format the header columns(Color,Pattern,etc.)
            using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A1:AA1"])
            {
                rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;             //Set Pattern for the background to Solid
                rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(79, 129, 189));  //Set color to dark blue
                rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White);
            }
            //End Format the header columns
            //Give the file details(ie. filename, etc.)
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Inventory Report " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + ".xlsx");
            //Write the file
            Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
            Response.End();
            pck.Save();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

what you would need is [epplus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), this will help you to create 2007+ excel file

not compatible with 2003 and under

Answer (score 0):

There is no really easy way depending of the version of excel file you want to write. If you want to go for xls you won't have much options than using Excel interop which would also have the dependency to have Excel installed.
The newer version offers some more options as it is just XML in the background. You can choose yourself how to create it, either yourself, some libraries or again Interop.
If you just want to display a table without any styling, there was (afair) a way to write csv file and excel can open it quite well (depending on the data types you want to use in it).